# Is convex program with exponential constraints NP-Hard

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, programming, np-complete

Convex optimization is widely known to be solvable in polynomial time, but is it still true when a convex program has an exponential number of constraints? For example, I have a convex program as follows, where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times d}$ (suppose $N$ is a super large number that is exponential to the input size), $f(x):\mathbb{R}^{N \times d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function (e.g. cross-entropy of $N$ distributions), $a \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times d}$ is constants:

$$
\text{min}_x \sum_i a_i x_i + f(x)
$$

$$
\text{subject to} \quad a_i x_i \ge a_i x_j \quad \forall i, j \in \{1, \cdots, N\}
$$

Obviously, the above program is a convex program but has exponential constraints. Can it still be efficiently solved, or is it actually NP-Hard?

Comment: for any $d$ it's a finite number of (linear) constraints - this is not NP hard.

Comment: @mordecai iwazuki, I don't understand, did you mean as long as $N$ is a finite number, this is not NP-Hard? If so, how can we solve this in polynomial time given the (finite) exponential constraints?

Comment: I don't see how $N$ can be possibly exponential in the input size. Part of that input is $a \in \mathbb R^{N \times d}$, right?

Comment: @Misha Lavrov, sorry about the confusion. There are some contexts I did not discuss. You can assume there are some other inputs (e.g. size $m$).  $a$ and $x$ are variables I constructed to solve the problem and $d=poly(m)$ while $N=exp(m)$.

Comment: Well, in this limited context, we can't possibly have a $\text{poly}(m)$ strategy. Just reporting a solution $x$ will have $\exp(m)$ complexity. If there is anything to be done, it is in exploiting the structure we do not see.